# How can I update "event.clientX" every sec?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to console log x coordinate every 1 sec when pointer is on picture but I have no idea how to update "event" from the js code.

```js
function onPic(event) {
  let xOnPic = event.clientX;
  console.log(xOnPic);
  setTimeout(onPic, 1000);
}
```

```css
.testDiv {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-image: url("./Pic/pic1.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 700px 350px;
}
```

```html
  <div onmouseover="onPic(event)" src="./Pic/pic1.jpeg" class="testDiv">
  </div>
```

Comment: You cannot poll the mouse position, you need to get it from some event like mousemove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to throw the event more often. Use `onmousemove` for that. If you want to restrict the amount of outputs you can do that with a variable.

```js
var wait = false

function onPic(event) {
  if (!wait) {
    wait = true;
    let xOnPic = event.clientX;
    console.log(xOnPic);
    setTimeout(() => wait = false, 1000);
  }
}
```

```css
.testDiv {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-image: url("./Pic/pic1.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 700px 350px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>I have no title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div onmousemove="onPic(event)" src="./Pic/pic1.jpeg" class="testDiv">
  </div>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

I should note that this will only trigger if the mouse actually moved in between, but that is what you usually want.

If you always want to update simply set an variable and output that every second.

```js
let interval = null;
let xPos = 0;

function onEnter() {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(xPos);
  }, 1000);
}

function onMove(event) {
  xPos = event.clientX;
}

function onLeave() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

```css
.testDiv {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-image: url("./Pic/pic1.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 700px 350px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>I have no title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div onmouseenter="onEnter(event)" onmousemove="onMove(event)" onmouseleave="onLeave(event)" src="./Pic/pic1.jpeg" class="testDiv">
  </div>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a working fiddle. Just use mouseenter mouseleave and mousemove and set Intervall.

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ym5covkL/1/)

**HTML**

```
<svg id="svg" class="pic">
</svg>
```

**JS**

```
let mouseInPic = false;
let x;
$("#svg").on("mouseenter", () => {
  mouseInPic = true
})
$("#svg").on("mouseleave", () => {
  mouseInPic = false
})
$("#svg").on("mousemove", (e) => {
    x = e.clientX
})

 window.setInterval(function(){
 if(mouseInPic == true){
    console.log(x)
 }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a native JS implementation, with 1 second throttling of the updates, so it will console the position every second but not more often than every second.  Since it is not possible to get the mouse position without a mouse event when mouse is over the element but not moving, you will need to remember the position of the mouse and store it into global variable, if mouse is moved on `mousemove`, just update the new position `xOnPic`.
Use `mouseover` and `mousemove` to detect if mouse is over the selected element and `mouseout` to detect when mouse is out of the element, so that you can stop printing to console.

```js
var xOnPic = 0
var mouseOverPic = false;
var tryingToUpdate = false;

function tryToUpdate(){
  if (!tryingToUpdate){
    tryingToUpdate = true
    console.log(xOnPic);
    setTimeout(onPic, 1000);
  }
}

function onPic(){    
    if (mouseOverPic){
      console.log(xOnPic);
      setTimeout(onPic, 1000);
    }else{
       tryingToUpdate = false;
    }
}

document.getElementById('Pic').addEventListener('mousemove',        function(e){
      xOnPic = e.clientX;
      mouseOverPic = true;
      tryToUpdate();
    });

document.getElementById('Pic').addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
      xOnPic = e.clientX;
      mouseOverPic = true;
      tryToUpdate();
  });

document.getElementById('Pic').addEventListener('mouseout', function(e){
      xOnPic = ''; 
      mouseOverPic = false;
  });
```

```css
.testDiv{
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-image: url("./Pic/pic1.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 700px 350px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>I have no title</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "test.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='Pic' src="./Pic/pic1.jpeg" class = "testDiv">
    
    </div>
    <script src = "test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
    setInterval(onPic,1000);

Comment: Their setTimeout calls the function it is in so it is already going to be calling onPic in a continuous fashion, no need to change to setInterval, as it would be creating numerous timers

Comment: @PatrickEvans that and this won't update the event. You do not even give the function a parameter (hence the error `"Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined"`). If you want the same event again, you can use `setInterval(() => onPic(event),1000);`, but that will just output the same coordinates over and overj